# Delete sent SMS from SMS apps without root

Tags: android, android-studio, sms, root

Good night!
Well, I have a simple question.

It is possible to delete sent SMS messages from "outbox"?
(Don't leave it like "Sent message" in Hangouts or another SMS app).

Im trying to do that without root permissions or any other thing.

If there is a little possibility to do that, can you explain me or help me with it?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Do you want to do this programatically? Otherwise, since you're root, you can always use sqlite3 to modify the database directly from the shell...

Comment: Yeah! I want to do that automatically without root because my app is to an asociation of womans with gender violence. Then, the SMS sent by my app mustn't be in "Sent Messages"

Comment: On recent Android versions all sent messages are persisted automatically by the platform so there's no way to send SMS under the radar.. and recent Android versions protect write access to the database by means of AppOps where the default app is given write access while other messaging apps are not.. Can you rely on data? If so you could use GCM messages instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, we can do nothing to delete sent sms. Every vendor like samsung, sony, ... have their own sms application. Just a little vendor use default android sms application in stock rom.

Each of android rom have different app to receive coming sms. So, no way to catch that sms from that application.

Beside it, android is sandbox mechanism, you can't affect to another application without root permission and do some trick.

Comment: This answer is, at best, incomplete, and just wrong on several points.